# Double hashing in open addressing, what hash function and table length

Tags: algorithm, double-hashing

In Cormen's book "Introduction to algorithms" I read that double hashing (in open addressing) function is in the form of:

```
h(k, i) = (h1(k) + i * h2(k)) mod m
```

where **k** is a key, **i** is a next index in the case of a collision, **m** is the table length and **hX** are hash functions.

He says that the main problem in double hashing is to utilize all indices in the table. To solve that problem we should set **m** to the power of 2 and **h2** function should return odd values. Why (I can't see him explaining it)?

Comment: If h_2(k) is odd, then h_2(k)*i won't be a multiple of m until i = m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that modulo `m`, adding `h_2(k)` repeatedly is a cycle that repeats with period `m/GCD(m, h_2(k))`.  If there are no common factors between `m` and `h_2(k)` then it will repeat with period `m` which means that you can reach all `m` indices.  So you want no common factors.

The "no common factors" rule is easily satisfied by making `m` a power of 2 and `h_2(k)` odd.

Comment: you mean GCF (Greatest Common Factor) instead of GCD, right?

Comment: I still don't feel it, I am not that good with numbers, but I made an example with 8-elements table and h_2(k) = 3. When I am increasing the "i" value it always hits another free place in the table, it's great :)

Comment: How do you come up with the m/GCF(m, h_2(k))? Is it something that must be memorized?

Comment: I meant "Greatest Common Divisor".  Which is also the greatest common factor.  As for why, suppose that you get a repeat after `l` steps.  Then `l*h_2(k)` is a multiple of `m`.  And vice versa if `l*h_2(k)` is a multiple of `m`, then you will repeat after `l` steps.  From this, the first repeat is at `m/GCD(m, h_2(k))`.